# Need help on forward compatibility check of Java class/jar file

Tags: java, automation

My requirement is, I have a third party jar file and I am using Java 1.6 now. But due to version upgrade/migration the application needs to  be moved to JAVA 1.8. I need a tool/utility/standalone program that will inspect my class/jar file and will give a summary/report which will tell whether there is any compliance issue.

For ex - Method deprecation. Thread.stop() is deprecated. The existing code will not run in higher version and will throw exception.

Comment: Just use JAVA 1.8 in your project and try to compile. That's the best overview of what will not work-

Comment: Build it with Java 1.8 and see where it breaks? Fix it then?

Comment: If that doesn't suffice have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html to see what was deprecated.

Comment: Good for single file. Trying achieve it for thousand of files, as part of migration. There are some tools mentioned here, but not doing the exact thing I am looking i guess https://lvc.github.io/japi-compliance-checker/

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for doing this ist the java compiler. It can tell you what will not work anymore (errors) and which classes/methods are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not in a position to run the class/jar on different java compiler/different JRE one by one. Because I am trying to achieve to do it automatically for a bulk number of files. Please share your idea.

Comment: Can you change the used JDK in the whole project? The compiler will then check every single file one by one - no further manual intervention needed by you.

Comment: Basically looking for some tool that checks for third party jar dependency whether that will be compatible in higher version. I know it can be done manually, but trying to make it automated if possible.

Comment: Please read my answer and my comments. I don't know where you transform my "automated" to "manually". If you want to migrate to a new Java version then you have to install that java version and try to run the application with that new version. You will get AUTOMATED a full list (even for external jars) of what will not work anymore and what is deprecated in the new version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am looking for something like below ->
java -jar <tool/utility.jar> <my.jar> <desired java version>.
This should give a compliance check. This is kind of pre-check before the migration.

Comment: If you don't want to use the newer java version - how should the older version know what would compile/not compile in a newer (at this point unknown) java version? That doesn't make any sense.
Changing the used JDK of the project is not hard and you can change it back at any time. The reason why you can't find a tool that provides a forward-compliance-check is that it doesn't make any sense and won't work.

Comment: Thanks sarkasronie for your time.